# What is the correct definition and usage of the acronym "ETA"?

Tags: acronyms

Does "ETA" stand for "Estimated Time *to* Arrival" or "Estimated Time *of* Arrival"? I most commonly hear phrases like "ETA 20 minutes", but I've also heard "ETA 4:30 PM". Is one usage correct and the other wrong, or are both okay?

Comment: _Of_ - that part is [general reference](http://www.onelook.com/?w=ETA&ls=a).

Comment: In general, it is much more likely that a term denoting a constant will have a special name than a term denoting a constantly-changing variable, which is what _estimated time to arrival_ would be. If it were even as good as MicroSoft Windows at estimating times, it would not be a useful thing to know.

Comment: @JohnLawler off-topic nitpick: the word _Microsoft_ has never been CamelCased, ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ETA](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ETA) appears to be [defined](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eta) as the *estimated time **of** arrival*.

It's fine to use either format. *ETA* is used to answer the question, *"When is X expected to arrive?*", which can be answered either as, "In 20 minutes" or "At 4:30 PM". In other words, either usage is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's *of*, but that doesn't matter, because that allows both uses.

> The estimated time of arrival is 10:37.

Fine, it's estimated that the person, item, etc. will arrive at 10:37.

> The estimated time of arrival is 20minutes.

Fine, there's an implied context of the current time, so it's the same as "The estimated time of arrival is 20minutes from now."